# Como puedo re asignar de forma correcta esta variable?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, variables

¿cómo están?, En el momento me encuentro aprendiendo Angular y entre ello, estoy haciendo un CRUD en el cual estoy siguiendo este video [CRUD en Angular](https://youtu.be/nEfemck6iNk?t=1901) pero en esa parte exactamente del video tengo un error y no he podido solucionarlo en la parte de `this.value = navigation?.extras?.state;`

me aperece

`Type '{ [k: string]: any; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'null'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'null'.ts(2322)`

he revisado la siguiente solucion, pero no he dado dar con la solucion [Typescript: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496398/typescript-type-string-undefined-is-not-assignable-to-type-string)

Este es mi codigo

edit.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit',
  templateUrl: './edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit.component.scss']
})
export class EditComponent implements OnInit {

  value = null;

  constructor(private router: Router) { 
    const navigation = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
    this.value = navigation?.extras?.state;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationExtras, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.scss'],
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
    state: {
      value: null,
    },
  };

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  onGoToEdit(item: any): void {
    this.navigationExtras!.state!['value'] = item;
    this.router.navigate(['edit'], this.navigationExtras);
  }

  onGoToSee(item: any): void {
    this.navigationExtras!.state!['value'] = item;
    this.router.navigate(['details'], this.navigationExtras);
  }

  onGoToDelete(item: any): void {
    alert('Deleted');
  }
}
```

Si me pudieran ayudar con la solución estaría agradecido gracias.

Comment: yo de ts no entiendo nada pero capaz si le metes un ``this.value = navigation?.extras?.state || null;`` ahi te ahorras el problema si llega undefined, no?

Comment: no, sigue igual :( , aparece

Comment: Type '{ [k: string]: any; } | null' is not assignable to type 'null'.
  Type '{ [k: string]: any; }' is not assignable to type 'null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el código del tutorial que seguís  es para la versión 11 ahora hay restricciones en tsconfig.json que hacen que el código tenga en cuenta las asignaciones que comentas.

> Cuando un valor es nulo o indefinido, debemos probar esos valores
> antes de usar métodos o propiedades con ese valor. Al igual que
> verificar si no está definido antes de usar una propiedad opcional los
> valores que pueden ser nulos o indefinidos no se pueden acceder
> normalmente, y los valores nulos e indefinidos no se pueden asignar a
> una propiedad de cualquier tipo si
>
> strictNullChecks esta en on Podes ver la teoría de como tener esto en
> cuenta en:

[strictNullChecks
on](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-)

También la forma de trabajar con uniones de tipos estrechándolos ( Narrowing) mediante la comprobación de su tipo con typeof

> Para Non-null Assertion Operador (Postfix !):

> TypeScript también tiene una sintaxis especial para eliminar valores
> nulos e indefinidos de un tipo sin realizar ninguna verificación
> explícita. operador! después de cualquier expresión es efectivamente
> una afirmación de tipo de que el valor no es nulo o indefinido
>
> Son algunas de las cosas a tener en cuenta para que el código de tu
> ejemplo funcione en las nuevas versiones de Angular

```
----------------------------------------------
src/app/shared/components/employee-form/employee-form.component.ts:15:3 - error TS2564: Property
 'employeeForm' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
Lo solucionamos con ! Escritura ! después de cualquier expresión es efectivamente
 una afirmación de tipo de que el valor no es nulo o indefinido:
 employeeForm!: FormGroup
-----------------------------------

src/app/shared/components/employee-form/employee-form.component.ts:38:50 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
const employeeId = this.employee?.id || null;
      this.employeesSvc.onSaveEmployee(employee, employeeId!);
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
src/app/shared/components/employee-form/employee-form.component.ts:50:14 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
isValidField(field: string): string {
    const validatedField = this.employeeForm.get(field);
    return (!validatedField?.valid && validatedField?.touched)
      ? 'is-invalid' : validatedField?.touched ? 'is-valid' : '';
  }
------------------------------------------------------------------
otro hay varios con lo mismo
onGoToEdit(): void {
    if ( this.navigationExtras.state?.value === 'undefined') {
      this.navigationExtras.state.value = this.employee;
      this.router.navigate(['edit'], this.navigationExtras);
    }

else{
// o de acuerdo a lo que se requiera
//this.navigationExtras.state!.value = this.employee;
      //this.router.navigate(['edit'], this.navigationExtras);
}
    
  }
----------------------------------
otro
async onGoToDelete(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      await this.employeesSvc.onDeleteEmployees(this.employee?.id!);
      alert('Deleted');
      this.onGoBackToList();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  onGoBackToList(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['list']);
  }


}
--------------------------
otro con 
 src/app/app.module.ts:25:49 - error TS2339: Property 'firebaseConfig' does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; }'.

25     AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)
lo debe de haber explicado en el tutorial o podes consultar esta pregunta que respondieron
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44033177/8957405
```

Aplique las correcciones para que pueda funcionar en el código que muestro salvo la ultima con respecto a firebase
para eso ya hay una  una forma de configuración en
[firebaseConfig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44033177/8957405)

> El codigo del tutorial con las correcciones anteriores

[tutorial](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BYjpUtMgSIuP_gWhO4pZlj4dLQXYdaAN?usp=sharing)
También hay otras formas de asignar null y evitar que no lo acepte Angular por ejemplo

```
const nulo={}as NavigationExtras;
    nulo?.state?.value!='hola'
```